# Using JQuery autocomplete, It keeps loading but it doesnt reach the function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am using JQuery autocomplete to call a php function through AJAX, this is my code:

```
$("#client").autocomplete("get_course_list.php",
{
  width: 260,
  matchContains: true,
  selectFirst: false
});
```

What I get on the screen is the loading icon but it doesn't reach the php function, I even tried putting a die("reach") in the php function to check.

I have tested it on IE10 and Firefox and they both give the same error.

Here's the beginning of the part in the php file that I'm calling:

```
    die("REACH");
    $q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
    if(!$q) return;
    $qry      = "SELECT client_id FROM cms_users WHERE id = '".$_SESSION['User']['id']."'";
    $SelClids = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($qry));
    $SelClids = $SelClids['client_id'];
    ....
```

Comment: Show your `php` file. Also, try using the full url

Comment: @Darren I have added the php file to the question, I will try that full url and let you know

Comment: @Darren Yep, it worked with the full url. Thanks :)

Comment: Perfect, glad that worked :). A little tip, always check your networks tab, it'll tell you if you found the page or not and what was returned!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [autocomplete](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) widget can have the following source.

**Array**

1. An array of strings: `[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]`
2. An array of objects with `label` and `value` properties `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`

*The label property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The value will be inserted into the input element when a user selects an item. If just one property is specified, it will be used for both, e.g., if you provide only value properties, the value will also be used as the label.*

**String**

When a string is used, the Autocomplete plugin expects that string to point to a URL resource that will return JSON data. It can be on the same host or on a different one (must provide JSONP). The Autocomplete plugin does not filter the results, instead a query string is added with a term field, which the server-side script should use for filtering the results. For example, if the source option is set to `"http://example.com"` and the user types foo, a GET request would be made to `http://example.com?term=foo`. The data itself can be in the same format as the local data described above.

**Function**

The third variation, a callback, provides the most flexibility and can be used to connect any data source to Autocomplete. The callback gets two arguments:
A request object, with a single term property, which refers to the value currently in the text input. For example, if the user enters "new yo" in a city field, the Autocomplete term will equal "new yo".
A response callback, which expects a single argument: the data to suggest to the user. This data should be filtered based on the provided term, and can be in any of the formats described above for simple local data. It's important when providing a custom source callback to handle errors during the request. You must always call the response callback even if you encounter an error. This ensures that the widget always has the correct state.

When filtering data locally, you can make use of the built-in `$.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex` function. It'll take a single string argument and escape all regex characters, making the result safe to pass to new `RegExp()`.

**Back to your question**

1. You need to give the full path of the document `http://www.example.com/foo.php`
2. You need to return the data as an `JSON array`.

example:

`json_encode($your_db_data);`

*Accepts an array of strings, and an array of objects.*